# How to produce a nomogram for a conditional survival model?

Tags: r, survival, conditional

Conditional survival is the survival probability after already surviving a predeﬁned time period. The formula used for conditional survival (CS) was: CS(x|y) = S(x + y)/S(x), where S(x) represents overall survival at x years.

I used Cox proportional hazards models to evaluate predictors of overall survival. Now I want to know how to draw a nomogram to predict 5-year survival directly after surgery and given survival for 1, 2, 3 and 4 years after surgery.